# SSRS Line Chart not Displaying Horizontal Axis Month Values in String Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Thank you for taking time to read my Post.May I have your insight on my below challenge.

**DESIGN:**

I have designed a Line Chart in SSRS 2008 R2 BIDS.

The Chart dataset has the following Columns (Calender Year,Month,Values) returned from an MDX query.

The column 'Values' is the measures and the 'calendar Year' & 'Month'  columns are the Dimesions.

I have restricted or filtered the MDX query to return only 'Values' for 'Months' under 'Calendar Year' 2013

**PROBLEM:**

I would like to return Months under the SSRS Line chart Horizontal Axis (Category Groups).The problem is I am unable to 
return these Months in Month Names.

When I set Horizontal Axis Interval properties to `=Str(Fields!Month.Value)` and Interval Type `Months`

The Months are returned in Numeric format e.g '01/01/2013' instead of  'JANUARY'

Is anyone familiar with a workaround that I can imlementto return Months in Month Names.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi DId u try this in the horizontal axis properties.

```
**=monthname(Fields!month.Value)**
```